# RxAnadroid concatenating streams

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm making a simple weather app to learn RxAndroid and I'm faced with the following issue.
I first load cities I'm interested in and then ask for the weather of each one of them. 
**getCitiesUseCase** returns an `Observable<List<City>>` that I load from the data base. I send that list of cities to my view to display them and then ask for the weather individually (flatmap) inside the subscriber.

```
Subscription subscription = getCitiesUseCase.execute().flatMap(new Func1<List<City>, Observable<City>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<City> call(List<City> cities) {
            citiesView.addCities(cities);
            return Observable.from(cities);
        }
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber<City>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            subscriptions.remove(this);
            this.unsubscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(City city) {
            getCityWeatherUseCase.setLatLon(city.getLat().toString(), city.getLon().toString(), city.getId());
            getCityWeather(city);
        }
    });

    subscriptions.add(subscription);
```

Now the getCityWeather() method looks like this:

```
    private void getCityWeather(final City city) {
    subscriptions.add(getCityWeatherUseCase.execute().subscribe(new Subscriber<CityWeather>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(CityWeather cityWeather) {
            city.setCityWeather(cityWeather);
            citiesView.updateCity(city);
        }
    }));
}
```

Everything works fine and as expected, but the fact that I'm subscribing to an observer inside a subcriber doesnt feel right. I know rxJava lets you play around with subscribers to prevent this kind of things but I really dont know how to improve my code further. Keep in mind that I need a city in order to ask for its weather.
Merry chrismas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be the following.  (I'm using retrolambda - so wherever you see `->`, just replace with a new anonymous inner class).

Note that I'm using `flatMap` to spin up the weather data requests, rather than `Observable.concat` like your question suggests. The reason for this is that your scheduler (e.g. `io()`) will handle these in parallel and send the results through when they are available.  However, with `Observable.concat`, these requests would be serialized so they'd be forced to happen one at a time - nullifying the benefits of a thread pool like `io()`.

```
private class City {
    public String name;
    public City(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setWeather(Weather weather) { /*...*/ }
}

private class Weather {
    public String status;
    public Weather(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

private Observable<Weather> getWeather(City city) {
    // call your weather API here..
    return Observable.just(new Weather("Sunny"));
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Observable<List<City>> citiesObs = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<City>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<City>> subscriber) {
            // do work
            final List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            cities.add(new City("Paris"));
            cities.add(new City("Tokyo"));
            cities.add(new City("Oslo"));

            // send results
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(cities);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    });

    Observable<City> obs = citiesObs

            // inject a side effect
            .doOnNext(list -> {
                // pass `list` to your view here
            })

            // turn Observable<Iterable<T>> into Observable<T>
            .flatMapIterable(list -> list)

            // Map a city to an observable that fetches Weather data
            // Your scheduler can take care of these at once.
            .flatMap(city -> {
                return getWeather(city)

                        // another side effect
                        .doOnNext(weather -> {
                            city.setWeather(weather);
                        })

                        // map baack to city, just for the heck of it
                        .map($ -> city);

            });

    TestSubscriber sub = TestSubscriber.create();
    obs.subscribe(sub);
    sub.awaitTerminalEvent();
    sub.assertValueCount(3);
}
```

Also note that in order to take advantage of `io()`, you'd need to add a call to `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to tell the observable to begin doing work on the `io` thread pool.  When you want to pass control to another thread, for example your view, you could insert a `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before your side-effect (or mapping).  If you want to bounce control back to the background thread(s) for your weather calls, you could then add another call to `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` right before you `flatMap` to `getWeather(City)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to figure out your code, question: what do we need this for *.flatMapIterable(list -> list)* not sure what it's doing

Comment: Ok, nevermind I got it, that method is spliting the list of cities into individual ones so we can request their weather info. This works like a charm! it´s exactly what I was lookin for, thanks!. Regarding threading, Im using repository.getCities().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()); for each of my *use cases* (every time I create a observable)